# Delete a directory by defining a task in Maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, ant, pom.xml

I am new to Maven so I would really appreciate some help on this issue that I am facing:

I want to delete a directory by declaring a task in `pom.xml` but only if it exists.

I have tried the following:

```
<delete quiet="true" includeEmptyDirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/directoryToDelete" erroronmissingdir="false" includes="*/**" />
</delete>
```

This does not throw an error or stop the build if directory does not exist but it does not delete the directory or the files under it, if it exists either.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What directory do you want to delete? This should be cleaned with `mvn clean`...

Comment: The directory contains a compile time generated class which I need to keep updating as the definition of the class keeps updating remotely.

Comment: Ok then why isn't the generated class put under `target`? All generated content should be placed under this folder. This way it will be cleaned when running `mvn clean`.

Comment: But this is child module that is used by another parent module and does not by the definition of `target` have it generated

Comment: What do you mean? Every Maven project has a temporary build directory, which is by default `target`. Maybe you can update the question with more information?

Comment: Oh that I did not know. I mean I have 10 modules and only the upper most module (module containing these 10 child modules) has the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

See [Ant, Delete Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html):

> | quiet | If the specified file or directory does not exist, do not display a diagnostic message (unless Apache Ant has been invoked with the `-verbose` or `-debug` switches)

See [Ant, FileSet Type](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html):

> | erroronmissingdir | Specify what happens if the base directory does not exist. If true a build error will happen, if false, the fileset will be ignored/empty.

Comment: I understand the options but my question was when the directory exists then why isnt it deleting it.